# How to prove a statistic is sufficient using conditional probability argument?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to tackle a question, but don't know how to start it:

Components of a certain type are shipped in batches of size k. Suppose that whether or not
any particular component is satisfactory is independent of the condition of any other component, and that the long run proportion of satisfactory components is p. Consider n batches, and let Xi denote the number of satisfactory components in
the ith batch (i = 1, 2, . . ., n). Statistician A is provided with the values of all the Xi’s, whereas statistician B is given only the value of X = ∑Xi. **Use a conditional probability argument to decide whether statistician A has more information
about p than does statistician B.**

I know the answer is "no, stat A does not have more information", but I don't know why. I tried setting up the conditional probability, but no distribution function was given. Mind helping me solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have a sample with $n$ components. Then the procedure is as follows. You take one component and test whether this component is satisfactiry or not. You have two possible outcomes, let us say with probability $p=P(\mbox{ Component is satisfactory})$ and $1-p$ otherwise. You repeat this, take another component and so on. Each test is independent so $X=\{\mbox{ Number of satisfactory components}\}$ follows a binomial distribution $Bin(n,p)$ where $p$ is the proportion of satisfactory components.

One can think of a binomial distribution as a sum os single independent Bernoulli trials. That is
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
where each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli trial with probability of success $p$ (in this case meaning the component is satisfactory).

Clearly, an unbiased estimator for $p$ is to take a sample, count the number of satisfactory components and
$$\hat{p} = \frac{X}{n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1} X_i.$$

Already here we can see that the statistic $T(X_1,\dots, X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is sufficient for $p$.

Statistician $A$ is given the information $X_i$ of which components are satisfactory and which are not. Whilst statistian $B$ is only given the amount of $X$. You can see that this amount of information is enough to estimate $p$.

Mathematically speaking, a sufficient statistic $T(X)$ for $p$ is such that
$$P(X=x | T(X)=t, p) = P(X=x|T(X)=t)$$
where $X$ can be a vector.

If you look at the formula above this essentially means that the information of knowing $T(X)$ and/or $p$ is the same. In other words, $T(X)$ is sufficient (or provides with sufficient information).

In our case:
$$P(X_1=x_1, \dots, X_n=x_n| \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t ,p ) = P(X_1=x_1, \dots, X_n=x_n| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\frac{k}{n},p ) = P(X_1=x_1, \dots, X_n=x_n| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\frac{k}{n} )$$
where in the last step we see that $p$ is redundant, since we already know $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and hence this is enough to know $p$, so conditioning on redundant knowledge is useless.

Another rule of thumb for sufficient statistics is the following: You have some model/distribution function depending on some parameter $\theta$ and some statistic $T(X_1,\dots, X_n)$. You collect observations $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and want to do some inference on $\theta$. Then you compute the value of $T(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ which will infer $\theta$. Then $T$ is sufficient if when having collected the data set and computed $T(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ we can "throw away" our sample. It is not needed anymore. While if the value $T(x_1,\dots, X_n)$ happens not to be sufficient that means that you still can gather more information from the sample, so you should not "throw it away". A very illustrative and good example is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Example